# Reformatting a json tree using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

I have a json tree at hand, I want to reformat it.

**The input is somewhat like : **

```
[
   {
      "archive":{
         "LOGS":{
            "_files":[
               "zomp_download_20220601170001.log",
               "zomp_download_20220626170002.log"
            ]
         },
         "SUMMARY":{
            "_files":[
               "SUMMARY_zomp_report_2022-04-01.csv",
               "SUMMARY_zomp_report_2022-06-25.csv"
            ]
         },
         "_files":[
            "lexter_report_2022-04-01.csv",
            "lexter_report_2022-06-25.csv"
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

**and the expected output : **

```
[
   {
      "text": "archive",
      "nodes":[
         {
            "text":"LOGS",
            "nodes":[
               {
                  "text":"_files",
                  "nodes":[
                     {
                        "text":"zomp_download_20220601170001.log"
                     },
                     {
                        "text":"zomp_download_20220626170002.log"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "text": "SUMMARY",
            "nodes":[
               {
                  "text":"SUMMARY_zomp_report_2022-04-01.csv"
               },
               {
                  "text":"SUMMARY_zomp_report_2022-06-25.csv"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "text":"lexter_report_2022-04-01.csv"
         },
         {
            "text":"lexter_report_2022-06-25.csv"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I tried to iterate over it, but I am unable to think of any logic to do so. I tried to put the input in a file and read it as a json.

```
import json

f = open(file)
config_file = json.load(f)

def traverse_dict(d):
   for d_key in d.keys():
    if isinstance(d[d_key], dict):
        new_dict = {}
        new_dict["node"] = [d[d_key]]
        traverse_dict(d[d_key])
    else:
        new_dict = {}
        new_dict["text"] = d[d_key]
 
for i in config_file:
    traverse_dict(i)
    print(i)
```

I need help in python to convert the json input as the json output. Any help/indicative logic/ examples will be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a recursive function to achieve your goal :

```py
import json
def convert_to_tree(node):
    if isinstance(node, dict):
        return [{"text": key, "nodes": convert_to_tree(value)} for key, value in node.items()]
    elif isinstance(node, list):
        result = []
        for item in node:
            result.extend(convert_to_tree(item))
        return result
    else:
        return [{"text": node}]

def main():
    input_json = [
        {
            "archive": {
                "LOGS": {
                    "_files": ["zomp_download_20220601170001.log", "zomp_download_20220626170002.log"]
                },
                "SUMMARY": {
                    "_files": ["SUMMARY_zomp_report_2022-04-01.csv", "SUMMARY_zomp_report_2022-06-25.csv"]
                },
                "_files": ["lexter_report_2022-04-01.csv", "lexter_report_2022-06-25.csv"]
            }
        }
    ]

    output_json = convert_to_tree(input_json)
    print(json.dumps(output_json, indent=3))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this simple 1:1 transformation should do it -

```py
import json

def remap(t):
  if isinstance(t, dict): 
    for k, v in t.items():
      yield {"text": k, "nodes": list(remap(v))}
  elif isinstance(t, list):
    for v in t:
      yield from remap(v)
  elif isinstance(t, str):
    yield {"text": t}
  else:
    raise TypeError(f"Unsupported type: {t}")
```

```py
input = """
[
   {
      "archive":{
         "LOGS":{
            "_files":[
               "zomp_download_20220601170001.log",
               "zomp_download_20220626170002.log"
            ]
         },
         "SUMMARY":{
            "_files":[
               "SUMMARY_zomp_report_2022-04-01.csv",
               "SUMMARY_zomp_report_2022-06-25.csv"
            ]
         },
         "_files":[
            "lexter_report_2022-04-01.csv",
            "lexter_report_2022-06-25.csv"
         ]
      }
   }
]
"""
```

Decode the JSON, remap it, encode it, print it -

```py
print(json.dumps(list(remap(json.loads(input))), indent=2))
```

The remapped output -

```json
[
  {
    "text": "archive",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "text": "LOGS",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "text": "_files",
            "nodes": [
              {
                "text": "zomp_download_20220601170001.log"
              },
              {
                "text": "zomp_download_20220626170002.log"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "SUMMARY",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "text": "_files",
            "nodes": [
              {
                "text": "SUMMARY_zomp_report_2022-04-01.csv"
              },
              {
                "text": "SUMMARY_zomp_report_2022-06-25.csv"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "_files",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "text": "lexter_report_2022-04-01.csv"
          },
          {
            "text": "lexter_report_2022-06-25.csv"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```